# Installshield Limited Edition licencing on build server

Tags: tfs, licensing, installshield, tfsbuild

I have recently installed Installshield LE on my local PC for vs2010, built a package and now wanting it to be built on our build server. I have also installed it on our build server.

I am getting the error:

error : -7159: The product license has expired or has not yet been initialized.

I have logged onto the build server, started vs and entered in my licence code. However, this has has not resolved the error.

I have read about the stand alone version but that appears to be only available for premium edition. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to login/start VS and Installshield using the build account credentials? The license may be activated for you, but not the build account (not sure if it is a personal license).

Comment: This isn't a development question. It's a user product support question.

Answer (score 10):

if you are using the 2012 Spring edition of `Installshield LE` run the license activator on the build server at :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield\2012SpringLE\System\TSConfig.exe
```

The location may be different for other versions of Installshield LE.

You should be able to use the same activation code they sent you when you signed up for the Installshield LE,  according to the license it allows for installation on more than one machine for automated build purposes.

Answer (score 3):

InstallShield has online activation.  You'll need to request multiple license keys and activate them on different machines.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this issue on our TeamCity build server. Initially I was able to run TSConfig.exe as the build server user and that worked. After a disaster recovery exercise, however, TeamCity reported the license was expired again, but running TSConfig.exe didn't do the trick.

I ended up launching VS 2015 as the build server user and opened a new InstallShield project. Instead of informing me the license was expired it said the license was corrupted and needed to be repaired. It performed the repair and I'm back on track.

I didn't know it was an option until after, but TSConfig /repair likely would have done the trick without opening Visual Studio.