# InstallShield 2012 not initialized after reinstall

Tags: installshield, installshield-2012

I've moved my InstallShield2012Spring installation from my old machine to my new one.  I've followed all instructions as to returning the license, installing on the new machine, and then re-activating the product.  Product reactivated successfully.  I then ran the product as administrator the first time as instructed.  However, when I try to build an existing merge module project using Visual Studio 2008, (this worked fine on the old computer), I get the following error:

InstallShield has not been initialized.  Installshield must be run at least once by a user with Administrator or Power User Privileges.

I've run as administrator, both right click and run as admin and log in as admin.  Please help as I've been researching this issue for a month now with no success.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you contact product support team? I also had problems moving licenses to new machines. SAB-Licenses are bounded to MAC address and full versions maybe in some way too. My reactivations also terminated with a success info but it didn't work. At the end Flexera did "something" with our licenses.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes to mind is to run it as administrator once and then run a repair via Add/Remove programs. Then launching one more time as administrator. Also check the event logs and any other logs you can find from Installshield.

I just searched online, check this answer: [Installshield Limited Edition licencing on build server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480302/installshield-limited-edition-licencing-on-build-server)